# How to transfer all data from oracle 9i to oracle oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, exp, imp

1.**9i** version command（9i version contains a user taoTest,which 11g version not contain）：

```
exp system/* file=d:\exp_full.dmp full=y;
```

2.**11g** version command(create taoTest user which same as 9i version)：

```
create user taoTest identified by taoTest; 
grant sysdba to taoTest;
```

3.**11g** version command：

```
 imp system/* file=d:\exp_full.dmp full=y;
```

Following above three commands, there is an error

> “taoTest user not exist”

How to solve this problem?

Comment: your `system/*`  could to be a problem. which instance is it connecting to?

Comment: Too few initial data for the analysis of the situation. Give for analysis the log of export and import.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak Execute the following commands with the database administrator privileges. "system/*" is database administrator account and it is correct.

Comment: @Dmitry Demin Do you mean that show the error log ?

Comment: I mean the files, import.log export.log.
The last line of the export log must be
Export terminated successfully without warnings.

Comment: If you want to create a user with a case-sensitive name,
you must change the SQL `create user "taoTest" identified by taoTest;`

Comment: Check username in source DB `select * from all_users 
where username ='taoTest' ; `